# Django REST Framework view permissions not called

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

I am trying to create a custom permission for my view that allow read and write permissions to the owner of the model in the QuerySet but do not allow any permission/request to other users or un-authenticated ones.

> Source: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/

**View:**

```py
class My_classListCreateAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Model.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ModelSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsModelOwner]
```

**Permission:**

```py
class IsModelOwner(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # Permissions are only allowed to the owner of the model and admins.
        if request.user.is_staff == True:
            return True
        return obj.owner == request.user
```

unfortunately it seems that my view is not even calling my custom permission class. (I imported it etc.) If instead of my custom permission class, I use a default one like `permissions.isAuthenticatedOrReadOnly` that works instead. What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `has_object_permission` method is only called on objects, not on querysets, what this means is that on a list request it won't be called.

Your view only has list and create endpoints, neither of those use the object_permissions, use `has_permission` instead.

However i believe what you want to do is actually use the isAuthenticated permission combined with a modified get_queryset in your view

```py
class My_classListCreateAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Model.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ModelSerializer
    permission_classes = [isAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Model.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Yes, so I thought there was a way to do it as a custom permission but I end up overriding the get_queryset method